# Adding a post shortcode to a page template?

Tags: plugins, php, page-template

hey guys,
The "mingle forum plugin" provides the following shortcode [mingleforum].
When I paste this into a page the forum is shown.

My forum is using a specific page-template called forum.php. Is it possible to already include this shortcode in the page-template itself, so I don't have to paste it in the wordpress backend anymore. So that when I use the forum.php page template the forum is always automatically embedded?

Thank you for your tipps and info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use shortcode in a PHP file (outside the post editor) you have the handy little function 
[do_shortcode();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)

so in your case you use:

```
<?php
do_shortcode('[mingleforum]');
?>
```

### Update:

following the first comment, 
I figured its publicly known for some reason,

**if you are expecting output from the shortcode then echo it out**.

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode('[mingleforum]');
?>
```

Comment: thank you! I had to do echo do_shortcode, but it worked!

Comment: updated for future lurkers :)